# The Cauchy product of two different power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

What is the cauchy product of two different power series from $0$ to $n$.

For example if $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are written in power series. How would you multiply the power series out and still end up having a power series?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know Cauchy product?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n, g(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$. Then their Cauchy product is
$$f(x)g(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n, \quad\text{where}\quad c_n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}a_{n-k}b_k $$